# How to apply texture only to one face in a THREE.js model for Autodesk Forge viewer

Tags: three.js, textures, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a model that has several objects loaded in an Autodesk forge viewer application which runs based on THREE.js.

**Expected results**

I need to change the texture of just one object's face, not the whole object.

**Current results**

Currently, I can change the texture of an object without problems, but the texture is applied to the whole object (all the faces).

[Codepen DEMO here](https://codepen.io/olavidps/pen/XWGmOdK)

[image]

**Issue description and hypothesis**

- I am using Autodesk's forge viewer, which uses THREE.js.
- I saw examples like this where you can change the texture of the clicked face of an object using `THREE.js raytracing` to get the clicked face and apply the texture to it. But it hasn't worked for me in Forge, I guess maybe there is some difference in doing it in forge viewer and doing it directly in THREE.js.
- I think the main issue is related to the way I am applying the texture. I think that I am explicitly applying the texture to the whole object, but I have not found a way to do this only in one face:

```js
const selectedIds = viewer.getSelection();
for (const dbId of selectedIds) {
  const fragIds = [];
  tree.enumNodeFragments(
    dbId,
    listFragmentProperties,
    false
  );
}
```

Your help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite difficult to implement in APS Viewer unfortunately. The SVF (our proprietary 3D format)  data that's being loaded into the viewer is optimized/baked for viewing, so while *certain* modifications are possible (for example, moving fragments around, or applying custom materials to them), there's limits to what can be done, at least without heavy hacking.

In your specific case, what you could do is extract just the vertices and triangles you need from the wall fragment (this *can* be done using the Viewer APIs), create a separate vanilla `THREE.Mesh` with them, and apply your texture to this object instead.